# Swipe and click events firing at the same time - Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am trying to allow swiping on a parent element and clicking on the child element. Currently the swipe and click is firing when I just want the swipe to fire.

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="broadcast__message__list__item">Try and swipe me</li>
</div>
```

JS

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
Hammer(slider).on("swipeleft", function() {
  console.log("swipe left");
});
Hammer(slider).on("swiperight", function() {
  console.log("swipe right");
});

$(document).on("click", ".broadcast__message__list__item", function(e) {
  console.log("click");
});
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/2ne/pen/GmYgmo?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to fix it but it is hacky and I couldn't use it in practise.

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var lastSwipe = 0;
Hammer(slider).on("swipeleft", function() {
  lastSwipe = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("swipe left");
});
Hammer(slider).on("swiperight", function() {
  lastSwipe = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("swipe right");
});

$(document).on("click", ".broadcast__message__list__item", function(e) {
  var t = new Date().getTime() - lastSwipe;
  if(t > 100) {
    console.log(t + " click");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add e.defaultPrevented to the swipe event

```
Hammer(slider).on("swipeleft", function(e) {
  if (e.defaultPrevented) return
  console.log("swipe left");
});
```